# Program isn't producing results

Tags: c

Hopefully I didn't screw up the code trying to indent all the lines. So basically, I have a program in C that takes user input, searches through arrays, and if it matches what's in the arrays, then print something. The second half of the arrays was just my programmatic way of putting the values there. I figured typing them out was the lazy way(in a sense).

Xcode is not showing any errors and almost every number the user types in should produce some sort of result but I can't even get that. When I run it, it asks for both inputs like expected, then just returns 0. At least if it was printing the wrong answer, I would be able to figure it out but this is probably something deeper that I just don't understand yet. Hopefully I did something stupid but I can't figure it out. Any help would be wonderful.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float sph;
float cyl;

float sixSevenFive[] = {6.5, 6.25, 6.0};
float six[] = {5.75, 5.5, 5.25};
float five[] = {5.0, 4.75, 4.5, 4.25};
float fourFive[] = {4.0, 3.75, 3.5};
float four[] = {3.25, 3.00, 2.75, 2.5, 2.25, 2.0, 1.75, 1.5, 1.25, 1.0, 0.75, 0.5,     0.25};
float three[8];
float two[7];
float one[6];
float zeroFive[7];
float zeroTwoFive[13];

// function to push values into arrays
void pushArray();
// function to find the base curve to use
void findBase();
// function to transpose sphere and cylinder
void transpose();

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
void pushArray();

printf("Enter sphere power: ");
scanf("%f", &sph);
printf("Enter cylinder power: ");
scanf("%f", &cyl);

void transpose();

void findBase();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please make a *minimal example*! This will also help your debug the issues yourself!

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the top of main, and ***step through your code***.  You will see your code is skipping functions.   Then you'll hopefully realize why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function calls are wrong inside `main`;

```
void pushArray();
void transpose();
void findBase();
```

Remove `void` from the function calls.

```
pushArray();
transpose();
findBase();
```

Comment: (you should specify that you mean *inside main*, because there are identical lines above main... where prototypes properly belong)

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I overlooked that.